# nfs server not running in 18.04?

Tags: xubuntu

I have an nfs server, however the nfs server isn't running at all.
It says

```
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-03-06 12:36:08 AEST; 1h 9min ago

$sudo systemctl status nfs-server
● nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2020-03-06 12:36:08 AEST; 1h 9min ago
  Process: 2908 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -f (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2907 ExecStopPost=/usr/sbin/exportfs -au (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2906 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd 0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2917 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2916 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2917 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

Mar 06 12:36:07 xxx-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Mar 06 12:36:08 xxx-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

I have tried using the following command to export the nfs.
The permission to my folder is 777. It has group of

```
sudo chown nobody:nogroup rootfs_microzed

#exportfs -ra

#exportfs 

sudo exportfs
/home/xxx/rootfs_microzed
        <world>
```

Basically, I am trying to use nfs to mount the rootfile system from embedded device zynq.
I am able to mount the root file system using my debian virtual machine. But, it can't 
mount using the ubuntu machine. I have used the same /etc/export settings.

```
/home/xxx/rootfs_microzed             *(rw,nohide,insecure,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,async)
```

I have tried restarting the nfs server also, but this didn't help.